# Referencing assemblies that are not part of .NET Standard

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-standard

I'm trying to make sense of which APIs are part of or compatible with .NET Standard.

Take for example [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=netframework-4.7.2).  It's not part of .NET Standard because it's a platform-specific API (i.e. the Microsoft Windows platform).  Accordingly, it's not listed in the "Applies To" section on MS Docs:

[image]

and [the .NET API Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=microsoft.win32.registry&view=netstandard-2.0) doesn't list anything for it in .NET Standard:

[image]

However, if I'm building a .NET Standard class library, I can the package from NuGet:

[image]

I don't get any warnings.  I thought it might have to do with the .NET Framework compatibility shim, but I set the version of .NET Standard below 2.0 and it still compiles.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is not part of .NET Standard, but is available as a Windows-only [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Win32.Registry/) which *targets* .NET Standard 2.0 (expand "Dependencies" on the Nuget listing page to verify). This is known as a "Platform Extension".

You can look this up on [apisof.net](https://apisof.net/catalog/Microsoft.Win32.Registry), where we see `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` support under ".NET Standard + Platform Extensions" but not - for the reason already stated - under ".NET Standard".